# using dynamic display message in the view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to set dynamic message inside $data['message']

for example, let say that on login form I want to display message please enter username and password, but on logoff action to dislay you are succ. logged out.

So I was thinking like

```
function login()
{
   $data['message'];
   if(!isset $data['message'])
   {
      $data['message'] = "please enter your username and password";
   }
   $this->load->view('login' $data);
}

function logout()
{
   unset session and .....
   $data['message'] = "You were succ. logged out!";
   $this->login($data);
}
```

but I'm getting following error on render login method

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting '('
```

inside line `if(!isset $data['message'])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(!isset($data['message']))
 { //etc...
```

isset requires the parentheses

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this..
you forgot bracket for `isset`

```
function login()
    {
       $data['message'];
       if(!isset($data['message']))
       {
          $data['message'] = "please enter your username and password";
       }
       $this->load->view('login' $data);
    }

    function logout()
    {
       //unset session and .....
       $data['message'] = "You were succ. logged out!";
       $this->login($data);
    }
```